# insert string within marker of matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 2D line plot:

```
d3 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9];
plot(d3, '-ob');
```

I would like to know how to insert a value into the markers of the line plot, such as inserting the y values into the center of the markers. For example:

[image: example]

Would this be possible?

Comment: yes it would be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) and properly adjust the [text properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html) to suit your purpose. You may have to play with the marker size and text alignment, but it's a fairly straightforward process.

For example:

```
% plot the data
figure
d3 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9];
n = 1:numel(d3);
plot(n,d3, '-ob','markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','w');

% step through the points in d3 and display a text label for each of them
for idx = 1:numel(d3)
    text(n(idx),d3(idx), num2str(d3(idx)),...
         'FontSize',8,...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
end
```

[image]

Comment: If you type this into matlab the result does not look very good at all. I was hoping there was a better way than using text. In order to make this better do I have to manually set the size of the markers, make the marker color white, and then manually set the size of the font in order to make it fit into the marker. Doesn't seem like a very useful solution.

Comment: @Kate: Shai's answer is correct, you just needed to read the documentation for text and text properties.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of plotting digits in circle using some special fonts (for example, *WingDings 2* has numbers in circle from digit 0 to 9). You may find some other free font with 2 digits in circle or square.

Here is the sample code.

```
font_numberCircle = 'WingDings 2';

x = 1:6;
y = rand(1,6);
m = {'j','l','n','o','q','r'}; %the markers to be plotted ('j' is 1 and 'r' is 9

figure('Color', 'w');
plot(x, y, 'r');
text(x, y, m, 'FontName', font_numberCircle, ...
    'FontSize', 40, 'FontWeight', 'bold', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center' )
set(gca, 'XLim', [0 7], 'YLim', [-0.1 1.1] );
```

[image: plot with special markers - workaround]